# Passing arguments when setting onclick in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Alright, i've been looking everywhere for a way to do that.

I have a list of buttons that are supposed to delete a table row when they are clicked on. I can't write a onclick directly in the HTML file because some of those table row can be added or deleted by the user, so I added them in Javascript:

```
    function setOnclick() {

        var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("delete-btn");

        for(var i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; ++i){
        deleteBtn[i].onclick = deleteArticle(/*(this)*/);
        }
    }

    function deleteArticle(article){
        /* delete the article row from table  */
    }
```

Now I cannot put any arguments because if I put () at the end of the function it's going to launch it instead of just assinging it.

PS: Since this is an assignment, I'm not authorized to use jQuery.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments to event listener, `.bind()` can be used:

```js
function setOnclick() {
  var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("delete-btn");
  for(var i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; ++i){
    deleteBtn[i].onclick = deleteArticle.bind(deleteBtn[i], 'some_more_parameter');;
  }
}

function deleteArticle(param){
  // DOM operation with "this"
  alert(this.innerText + ' & ' + param);
}

setOnclick();
```

```html
<button class="delete-btn">
xxx
</button>
<button class="delete-btn">
yyy
</button>
```

Comment: It looks pretty good i'll try it and give you feedback ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: It worked perfectly and it even made me notice another error in my code, thanks a lot my friend !

Comment: @LudoB99: This is a pointless use of `.bind()`. Doing `deleteBtn[i].onclick = deleteArticle;` like avril's answer shows does exactly the same thing but more efficient.

Comment: @zippydippy I realized if only `this` is binded, it does not add/change any function in this scenario. I've edited the answer and pass an additional parameter to show what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should put

```
...
deleteBtn[i].onclick = deleteArticle
...

function deleteArticle(){
 this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

Comment: Yes I know how to do that :) My problem is that I can't add (this) to my onclick because it will run the function and I just want it to be assingned to my button... Sorry if I'm not beign clear i'm starting to learn JS.

Comment: @LudovicBelzile If you want to pass `this` or other parameters to event listener, `.bind` can be used. Please check my answer.

Comment: @LudovicBelzile well thought

Comment: @LudovicBelzile You do not have to call the function. Look again my code

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clouser function.

```
 function setOnclick() {

    var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("delete-btn");

    for(var i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; ++i){
       let article = deleteBtn[i];
       article.onclick = function() {
          deleteArticle(article);
       }

    }
}

function deleteArticle(article){
    /* delete the article row from table  */
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will pass `undefined` every time.